# Convert uploaded GIF to non animated image automatically

Tags: images, uploads

Is there a way to convert automatically uploaded GIF to JPEG or PNG (non animated) and keep the original?

Comment: how is it specific to wordpress?

Comment: I don't think there is any API to convert images to different format in wordpress. You can do it is php check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872703/php-image-convert  and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755781/convert-jpg-image-to-gif-png-bmp-format-using-php